# Does it make any difference to include or omit :latest when pulling a Docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Most people seem to include image:latest in either their **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:latest
```

Or **docker-compose**:

```
image: node:latest
```

However, it seems to download the latest version as well when pulling the image without `:latest`, resulting in:

```
FROM node
```

Is there any difference between including `:latest` or not?

*I understand that it is a must when wanting to pull an image which is not the latest.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it makes no difference.

A `Dockerfile` without `:latest` when having `node:boron` installed, pulls the latest image from the docker hub. `docker build -t "img" .`:

```
...
Step 1/7 : FROM node
latest: Pulling from library/node
...
Digest: sha256:c7505048a3ddc2539b9b4d7c468e6ff0641f3a06ec95a4450be493fec8410c13
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
 ---> efe7b69d7b71
```

A Dockerfile with `:latest` when having run the previous command, still tries the take the same image: `docker build -t "a" .`:

```
...
Step 1/7 : FROM node:latest
 ---> efe7b69d7b71
```

Notice that it still tries to pull the latest, and both have the same sha.